# Unable to open the socket program header in VS2008

Tags: c++, c, sockets, visual-studio-2008, network-programming

**idevs.h, netinet/in_systm.h, netinet/ip.h, netinet/tcp.h  openssl/ssl.h sys/socket.h**

These header files can work in Linux but in visual studio 2008 compile error says unable to open header file. These are socket program related headers. (I am unable to get any proper result from web search)

**Problem:**

Please let me know any dll I have include for these headers or any other equivalent headers are available ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [MSDN has the details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Below both are correct and useful answers, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets are not part of the C++ standard and are implemented in different ways in Linux and Windows. That means, that the native socket libraries are different in both OSes, and Windows has other headers for its socket API than Linux. So you will not only have to include other headers but might also need to use other functions.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might want to use a library that wraps the OS specific parts and provides a portable interface. There are several more or less portable networking libraries, one of the best known might be Boost.Asio

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response

Answer (score 1):

In windows environment you need to include the windows specific headers like `winsock.h` and others (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx). You need to switch between headers using the `#ifdef` statements when doing builds for different platforms.

Nobody ever promised that windows implementation of the sockets concept is 100% identical to the one of Unix. These implementations have a lot in common, but differences are also present.